# Find index of an element from the List in Groovy

Tags: java, list, indexing, groovy

```
def String curMonth = cube.getSubstitutionVariableValue('StartMth').toString()
```

The above line gives an output of 'P09' and stores its `curMonth` variable

```
List<String> moDictionary = ['P01','P02','P03','P04','P05','P06','P07','P08','P09','P10','P11','P12','P13']

int idxStartMonth = moDictionary.indexOf(curMonth)

List openMonths = moDictionary[idxStartMonth..12]
```

If I print value of `idxStartMonth` I receive -1 instead of 8. But if I replace `curMonth` and hardcode 'P09' then I get the correct results.

How can I fix this code so it picks the curMonth value correctly?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried printing out the value of `curMonth` in `def String curMonth = cube.getSubstitutionVariableValue('StartMth').toString()` using something like `println(sprintf("value: |%s|", curMonth))` to make sure there's no unexpected characters in the value ie blank spaces?

Comment: I did that but and there are no special characters.

Comment: There are 2 potential causes here. 1. `curMonth` is not a `java.lang.String` or 2. `curMonth` contains characters not in the strings in the list. That's the only reasons. If it is a string with exactly the same chars, indexof would work as you expect

Comment: Trying your code locally shows it works fine. The only thing unknown to
us is `cube.getSubstitutionVariableValue('StartMth')`; Please provide
a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
- there is something missing and we can only guess.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who replied....There was a single quote around the value of StartMth which was causing this. Removing it fixed the issue.